# iOS Core Data - Why it works?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am confused of the core data's logic.

I treated the core data as a database, and core data methods as a SQL query.

When I tried to update some object in a core data with a local memory's object, I found that I can make the feature just with below code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", theBook.identifier];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
Book *book = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error getting book to update: %@", error);
    abort();
}

// NSLog(@"%d", book == theBook);

error = nil;
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving the book: %@", error);
    abort();
}
```

`theBook` is the object which I want to update the core data's object with.

And I found that the log message says the two objects are same...

I fetched the request and didn't do anything but it works. Why does it work?

Comment: I found that it works when I used only the save section of the code. I think it is because `theBook` is also a result of fetch.

Comment: your question is not clear at all. and I cannot see why it will not work.

Comment: When I treat the core data as a database, I thought that I should (1) get an object from the fetch request and (2) edit the object's value and (3) then save. But it works when I omit the process (1) and (2). I'm not a native english user so it's hard to explain my question. Sorry :)

Comment: still not clear for me. you did fetch object from CoreData and process 2 is optional.

Comment: My question is why it is optional..

Comment: why it is not optional.... of cause you don't have to update the database and it will not break

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I think I misunderstood about the concept of core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first Core Data is not a database - it's an object graph, which could be saved to some kind of storage.
If your objects in there have unique `identifier`, then fetching with the same `identifier` value gives you the same object. Core Data does not create different instances of managed objects for the same entities (say book with identifier=7), so everywhere you'll deal with the same object, doesn't matter if you fetch it 15 times, you'll always end up with the same one.

Comment: It was a big help for me. I misunderstood about the core data.